# website zooms when opened in ipad. Also zooms more when tapped on some button

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, ipad

[image]I have written code in html, css, js.
It works properly on all devices except for ipad.
Emulator for ipad on google chrome shows that it works fine.

But when opened on ipad, the website zooms as soon as the website loads. When clicked on any button on the website, it zooms more.

mentioning the meta tag written in the code:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using safari on the iphone. Does it work correctly on a safari browser on a mac? Maybe isolate that one first.

Comment: It works perfectly fine in mac. In ipad this problem comes in safari as well as chrome

Answer (score 0):

After the IOS update for Ipad, the problem got solved on its own.